# What is wrong with this edit

Tags: discussion, editing

What’s wrong with [this edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/241090)?
I thought shortlinks were banned and should be removed.

Comment: Just ask @Allan in chat. No need to create an entire question based around it especially when you have already gotten the go-ahead from mods in your other question.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the editor now detects and prevents introduction of some new short links and we're asking people to go slowly with the edits to avoid flooding the queues. I do agree that in general we should avoid them, but perhaps there's a reason to keep them here that Allan can share.

It looks like there are some rollbacks so let's see if Allan can join us here or we can make a chat room (private if needed) to work out any disagreements on edits. So, unless that function changes - a rollback seems to be the only way to re-introduce a problematic shortening service that’s been hard coded (or configured) into the site editor.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/259064/revisions

For now, Matt - let's move on to another post and give this one some time to settle. You've made your suggested edits there twice so let's see if the author and you can come to an agreement?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services

Comment: I actually tried to edit a bit.ly link after @matt flagged me on an old post and the editor won't let you use bit.ly links any more.

Comment: @IanC. Wow - that’s cool. I’ve edited my answer as I’ve now received the memo, loud and clear.

Answer (score 2):

I rejected that edit because I was unaware of the "crusade" at the time and assumed it was superfluous.  When I got the notification, I just clicked "rollback".  Now that I'm aware of the crusade,  I've gone ahead and re-edited the answer deleting the link so it's no longer an issue.

Comment: Thanks Allan! I too took a while to see what the change was about. I still feel a little uneasy calling this a “crusade” since the connotation of decades of religious wars seems a little over the top so I like to think of it as a community effort : - )

Comment: @bmike Couldn't have said it better!  (And you usually do!)  :-)